# Latex2html: How to make table of contents not use a bullet?

Tags: latex2html, css

When I run LaTeX2HTML on a LaTeX file, the table of contents that is generated in the html file has bullets to the left of each section.

Like this:

```
o  this_is_section_one
o  this_is_section_two
```

If I use the option `-show_section_numbers` then the bullets remain and next to them I see the section numbers, like for example:

```
o  1. this_is_section_one
o  2. this_is_section_two
```

What I want is a table of contents with section numbers. No Bullets, like the following:

```
1. this_is_section_one
2. this_is_section_two
```

I do not know how to get rid of the bullets.

The commands I tried are

```
latex2html -split 4 KERNEL.tex 
latex2html -split 4 -show_section_numbers KERNEL.tex
```

In the LaTeX file itself, I tried with `\tableofcontents` and without `\tableofcontents`. Nonetheless, I still get the bullets.

The question is: how to get rid of the bullets? I hope there is an option or a flag to achieve this, but looking at the man page for LaTeX2HTML, I do not see it. Will keep trying, but I thought to ask here, in case someone knows.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the list-items have [bullets by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) in HTML files - expanding the LaTeX list-items bulleting/numbering.

To get rid of that default bullets from all of the lists, you need to **modify the CSS file** which was generated by LaTeX2HTML. Add the following code snippet to this file:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

(I have not used LaTeX2HTML, but come up against the same problem while working with TeX4ht.)